# Is the following a valid base64 encoded tif image response?

Tags: xml, web-services, encryption, base64

I am connecting to a web service that is supposed to get back a TIF image that is base 64 encoded. I am getting the following:

```
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
```

Is this a valid response for a tif image? All the online tools I am testing cannot make any sense of it so I do not know what is happening.

Comment: Are we supposed to eyeball it and know?

Comment: No the idea was you could copy paste to some tool and possibly help in determining if it was valid. Thanks for the sarcasm though.

Comment: Any time. The sarcasm was directed more at this question being off-topic.

Comment: I disagree. Detecting the validity of a web service output is very much in the realm of trouble shooting code. I stated an objective fact very much related to the tags in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - it is not a valid TIF.

#### Base64:

```
0x0000: PGhlYWQ+DQo8bGluayByZWw9J3N0eWxlc2hlZXQnIGhyZWY9Jy9fY29tbW9uL3N0
0x0040: eWxlcy5hc3B4Jz48L2xpbms+DQo8L2hlYWQ+DQo8c2NyaXB0IGxhbmd1YWdlPSdK
0x0080: YXZhU2NyaXB0Jz4NCg0KZnVuY3Rpb24gZm5Ub2dnbGVEZXRhaWxzKCkgew0KICAg
0x00C0: IHRyeSB7DQogICAgICAgIGlmICh4RGV0YWlscy5zdHlsZS5kaXNwbGF5LnRvVXBw
0x0100: ZXJDYXNlKCkgPT0gJ05PTkUnKSB7DQogICAgICAgICAgICB4RGV0YWlscy5zdHls
0x0140: ZS5kaXNwbGF5ID0gJyc7DQogICAgICAgICAgICB4RGV0YWlsc0J1dHRvbi52YWx1
0x0180: ZSAgID0gJ0hpZGUgRGV0YWlscyc7DQogICAgICAgIH0gZWxzZSB7DQogICAgICAg
0x01C0: ICAgICB4RGV0YWlscy5zdHlsZS5kaXNwbGF5ID0gJ25vbmUnOw0KICAgICAgICAg
0x0200: ICAgeERldGFpbHNCdXR0b24udmFsdWUgICA9ICdWaWV3IERldGFpbHMnOw0KICAg
0x0240: ICAgICB9DQogICAgfSBjYXRjaCAoZSkgew0KICAgIH0NCn0NCg0KPC9zY3JpcHQ+
0x0280: DQoNCjxwcmUgY2xhc3M9J0NUZXh0Jz4NCg0KQW4gdW5leGVjdGVkIGVycm9yIGhh
0x02C0: cyBvY2N1cnJlZC4NClRoZSBlcnJvciBoYXMgYmVlbiBsb2dnZWQuDQpJZiB0aGUg
0x0300: cHJvYmxlbSBwZXJzaXN0cyBwbGVhc2UgY29udGFjdCBzdXBwb3J0DQpvciB5b3Vy
0x0340: IHN5c3RlbSBhZG1pbmlzdHJhdG9yLg0KDQo8cHJlPg0KDQo8aW5wdXQgaWQ9J3hE
0x0380: ZXRhaWxzQnV0dG9uJyBjbGFzcz0nQ0J1dHRvbicgdHlwZT0nYnV0dG9uJyBvbmNs
0x03C0: aWNrPSdmblRvZ2dsZURldGFpbHMoKScgdmFsdWU9J1ZpZXcgRGV0YWlscycvPg0K
0x0400: DQo8YnIvPg0KPGJyLz4NCg0KPHNwYW4gaWQ9J3hEZXRhaWxzJyBzdHlsZT0nZGlz
0x0440: cGxheTogbm9uZTsnPg0KDQo8dGFibGUgY2xhc3M9J0NUZXh0Jz4NCiAgPHRyPjx0
0x0480: ZD5XZWIgSG9zdDo8L3RkPjx0ZD5GQVhTRVJWRVIuU0VDVVJFQ0FSRVRFQ0guQ09N
0x04C0: PC90ZD48L3RyPg0KICA8dHI+PHRkPldlYiBQb3J0OjwvdGQ+PHRkPjgwPC90ZD48
0x0500: L3RyPg0KICA8dHI+PHRkPlNlcnZlciBOYW1lOjwvdGQ+PHRkPmZheHNlcnZlcjwv
0x0540: dGQ+PC90cj4NCiAgPHRyPjx0ZD5Mb2NhbCBJUDo8L3RkPjx0ZD4xMC4xLjUuMTI8
0x0580: L3RkPjwvdHI+DQogIDx0cj48dGQ+TG9nIElEOjwvdGQ+PHRkPjIwMTEwNTA3LjAx
0x05C0: MTIxNDU1MzwvdGQ+PC90cj4NCjwvdGFibGU+DQoNCjxwcmUgY2xhc3M9J0NUZXh0
0x0600: Jz4NCg0KRXJyb3IgTWVzc2FnZToNCg0KRXJyb3IgY29udmVydGluZyBkYXRhIHR5
0x0640: cGUgbnZhcmNoYXIgdG8gYmlnaW50Lg0KDQpFcnJvciBTdGFjayBUcmFjZToNCg0K
0x0680: ICAgYXQgU3lzdGVtLkRhdGEuU3FsQ2xpZW50LlNxbENvbm5lY3Rpb24uT25FcnJv
0x06C0: cihTcWxFeGNlcHRpb24gZXhjZXB0aW9uLCBCb29sZWFuIGJyZWFrQ29ubmVjdGlv
0x0700: bikNCiAgIGF0IFN5c3RlbS5EYXRhLlNxbENsaWVudC5TcWxJbnRlcm5hbENvbm5l
0x0740: Y3Rpb24uT25FcnJvcihTcWxFeGNlcHRpb24gZXhjZXB0aW9uLCBCb29sZWFuIGJy
0x0780: ZWFrQ29ubmVjdGlvbikNCiAgIGF0IFN5c3RlbS5EYXRhLlNxbENsaWVudC5UZHNQ
0x07C0: YXJzZXIuVGhyb3dFeGNlcHRpb25BbmRXYXJuaW5nKFRkc1BhcnNlclN0YXRlT2Jq
0x0800: ZWN0IHN0YXRlT2JqKQ0KICAgYXQgU3lzdGVtLkRhdGEuU3FsQ2xpZW50LlRkc1Bh
0x0840: cnNlci5SdW4oUnVuQmVoYXZpb3IgcnVuQmVoYXZpb3IsIFNxbENvbW1hbmQgY21k
0x0880: SGFuZGxlciwgU3FsRGF0YVJlYWRlciBkYXRhU3RyZWFtLCBCdWxrQ29weVNpbXBs
0x08C0: ZVJlc3VsdFNldCBidWxrQ29weUhhbmRsZXIsIFRkc1BhcnNlclN0YXRlT2JqZWN0
0x0900: IHN0YXRlT2JqKQ0KICAgYXQgU3lzdGVtLkRhdGEuU3FsQ2xpZW50LlNxbERhdGFS
0x0940: ZWFkZXIuSGFzTW9yZVJvd3MoKQ0KICAgYXQgU3lzdGVtLkRhdGEuU3FsQ2xpZW50
0x0980: LlNxbERhdGFSZWFkZXIuUmVhZEludGVybmFsKEJvb2xlYW4gc2V0VGltZW91dCkN
0x09C0: CiAgIGF0IFN5c3RlbS5EYXRhLlNxbENsaWVudC5TcWxEYXRhUmVhZGVyLlJlYWQo
0x0A00: KQ0KICAgYXQgYXhhY29yZS5saWIuZGIuRGJTZXNzaW9uMy5SZWFkKCkNCg0KPC9w
0x0A40: cmU+DQoNCjwvc3Bhbj4NCg0K
```

#### Binary:

```
0x0000: 3C 68 65 61 64 3E 0D 0A 3C 6C 69 6E 6B 20 72 65   <head>..<link re
0x0010: 6C 3D 27 73 74 79 6C 65 73 68 65 65 74 27 20 68   l='stylesheet' h
0x0020: 72 65 66 3D 27 2F 5F 63 6F 6D 6D 6F 6E 2F 73 74   ref='/_common/st
0x0030: 79 6C 65 73 2E 61 73 70 78 27 3E 3C 2F 6C 69 6E   yles.aspx'></lin
0x0040: 6B 3E 0D 0A 3C 2F 68 65 61 64 3E 0D 0A 3C 73 63   k>..</head>..<sc
0x0050: 72 69 70 74 20 6C 61 6E 67 75 61 67 65 3D 27 4A   ript language='J
0x0060: 61 76 61 53 63 72 69 70 74 27 3E 0D 0A 0D 0A 66   avaScript'>....f
0x0070: 75 6E 63 74 69 6F 6E 20 66 6E 54 6F 67 67 6C 65   unction fnToggle
0x0080: 44 65 74 61 69 6C 73 28 29 20 7B 0D 0A 20 20 20   Details() {..   
0x0090: 20 74 72 79 20 7B 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20    try {..        
0x00A0: 69 66 20 28 78 44 65 74 61 69 6C 73 2E 73 74 79   if (xDetails.sty
0x00B0: 6C 65 2E 64 69 73 70 6C 61 79 2E 74 6F 55 70 70   le.display.toUpp
0x00C0: 65 72 43 61 73 65 28 29 20 3D 3D 20 27 4E 4F 4E   erCase() == 'NON
0x00D0: 45 27 29 20 7B 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20   E') {..         
0x00E0: 20 20 20 78 44 65 74 61 69 6C 73 2E 73 74 79 6C      xDetails.styl
0x00F0: 65 2E 64 69 73 70 6C 61 79 20 3D 20 27 27 3B 0D   e.display = '';.
0x0100: 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 78 44 65   .            xDe
0x0110: 74 61 69 6C 73 42 75 74 74 6F 6E 2E 76 61 6C 75   tailsButton.valu
0x0120: 65 20 20 20 3D 20 27 48 69 64 65 20 44 65 74 61   e   = 'Hide Deta
0x0130: 69 6C 73 27 3B 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 7D   ils';..        }
0x0140: 20 65 6C 73 65 20 7B 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 20    else {..       
0x0150: 20 20 20 20 20 78 44 65 74 61 69 6C 73 2E 73 74        xDetails.st
0x0160: 79 6C 65 2E 64 69 73 70 6C 61 79 20 3D 20 27 6E   yle.display = 'n
0x0170: 6F 6E 65 27 3B 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20   one';..         
0x0180: 20 20 20 78 44 65 74 61 69 6C 73 42 75 74 74 6F      xDetailsButto
0x0190: 6E 2E 76 61 6C 75 65 20 20 20 3D 20 27 56 69 65   n.value   = 'Vie
0x01A0: 77 20 44 65 74 61 69 6C 73 27 3B 0D 0A 20 20 20   w Details';..   
0x01B0: 20 20 20 20 20 7D 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 7D 20 63 61        }..    } ca
0x01C0: 74 63 68 20 28 65 29 20 7B 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 7D   tch (e) {..    }
0x01D0: 0D 0A 7D 0D 0A 0D 0A 3C 2F 73 63 72 69 70 74 3E   ..}....</script>
0x01E0: 0D 0A 0D 0A 3C 70 72 65 20 63 6C 61 73 73 3D 27   ....<pre class='
0x01F0: 43 54 65 78 74 27 3E 0D 0A 0D 0A 41 6E 20 75 6E   CText'>....An un
0x0200: 65 78 65 63 74 65 64 20 65 72 72 6F 72 20 68 61   exected error ha
0x0210: 73 20 6F 63 63 75 72 72 65 64 2E 0D 0A 54 68 65   s occurred...The
0x0220: 20 65 72 72 6F 72 20 68 61 73 20 62 65 65 6E 20    error has been 
0x0230: 6C 6F 67 67 65 64 2E 0D 0A 49 66 20 74 68 65 20   logged...If the 
0x0240: 70 72 6F 62 6C 65 6D 20 70 65 72 73 69 73 74 73   problem persists
0x0250: 20 70 6C 65 61 73 65 20 63 6F 6E 74 61 63 74 20    please contact 
0x0260: 73 75 70 70 6F 72 74 0D 0A 6F 72 20 79 6F 75 72   support..or your
0x0270: 20 73 79 73 74 65 6D 20 61 64 6D 69 6E 69 73 74    system administ
0x0280: 72 61 74 6F 72 2E 0D 0A 0D 0A 3C 70 72 65 3E 0D   rator.....<pre>.
0x0290: 0A 0D 0A 3C 69 6E 70 75 74 20 69 64 3D 27 78 44   ...<input id='xD
0x02A0: 65 74 61 69 6C 73 42 75 74 74 6F 6E 27 20 63 6C   etailsButton' cl
0x02B0: 61 73 73 3D 27 43 42 75 74 74 6F 6E 27 20 74 79   ass='CButton' ty
0x02C0: 70 65 3D 27 62 75 74 74 6F 6E 27 20 6F 6E 63 6C   pe='button' oncl
0x02D0: 69 63 6B 3D 27 66 6E 54 6F 67 67 6C 65 44 65 74   ick='fnToggleDet
0x02E0: 61 69 6C 73 28 29 27 20 76 61 6C 75 65 3D 27 56   ails()' value='V
0x02F0: 69 65 77 20 44 65 74 61 69 6C 73 27 2F 3E 0D 0A   iew Details'/>..
0x0300: 0D 0A 3C 62 72 2F 3E 0D 0A 3C 62 72 2F 3E 0D 0A   ..<br/>..<br/>..
0x0310: 0D 0A 3C 73 70 61 6E 20 69 64 3D 27 78 44 65 74   ..<span id='xDet
0x0320: 61 69 6C 73 27 20 73 74 79 6C 65 3D 27 64 69 73   ails' style='dis
0x0330: 70 6C 61 79 3A 20 6E 6F 6E 65 3B 27 3E 0D 0A 0D   play: none;'>...
0x0340: 0A 3C 74 61 62 6C 65 20 63 6C 61 73 73 3D 27 43   .<table class='C
0x0350: 54 65 78 74 27 3E 0D 0A 20 20 3C 74 72 3E 3C 74   Text'>..  <tr><t
0x0360: 64 3E 57 65 62 20 48 6F 73 74 3A 3C 2F 74 64 3E   d>Web Host:</td>
0x0370: 3C 74 64 3E 46 41 58 53 45 52 56 45 52 2E 53 45   <td>FAXSERVER.SE
0x0380: 43 55 52 45 43 41 52 45 54 45 43 48 2E 43 4F 4D   CURECARETECH.COM
0x0390: 3C 2F 74 64 3E 3C 2F 74 72 3E 0D 0A 20 20 3C 74   </td></tr>..  <t
0x03A0: 72 3E 3C 74 64 3E 57 65 62 20 50 6F 72 74 3A 3C   r><td>Web Port:<
0x03B0: 2F 74 64 3E 3C 74 64 3E 38 30 3C 2F 74 64 3E 3C   /td><td>80</td><
0x03C0: 2F 74 72 3E 0D 0A 20 20 3C 74 72 3E 3C 74 64 3E   /tr>..  <tr><td>
0x03D0: 53 65 72 76 65 72 20 4E 61 6D 65 3A 3C 2F 74 64   Server Name:</td
0x03E0: 3E 3C 74 64 3E 66 61 78 73 65 72 76 65 72 3C 2F   ><td>faxserver</
0x03F0: 74 64 3E 3C 2F 74 72 3E 0D 0A 20 20 3C 74 72 3E   td></tr>..  <tr>
0x0400: 3C 74 64 3E 4C 6F 63 61 6C 20 49 50 3A 3C 2F 74   <td>Local IP:</t
0x0410: 64 3E 3C 74 64 3E 31 30 2E 31 2E 35 2E 31 32 3C   d><td>10.1.5.12<
0x0420: 2F 74 64 3E 3C 2F 74 72 3E 0D 0A 20 20 3C 74 72   /td></tr>..  <tr
0x0430: 3E 3C 74 64 3E 4C 6F 67 20 49 44 3A 3C 2F 74 64   ><td>Log ID:</td
0x0440: 3E 3C 74 64 3E 32 30 31 31 30 35 30 37 2E 30 31   ><td>20110507.01
0x0450: 31 32 31 34 35 35 33 3C 2F 74 64 3E 3C 2F 74 72   1214553</td></tr
0x0460: 3E 0D 0A 3C 2F 74 61 62 6C 65 3E 0D 0A 0D 0A 3C   >..</table>....<
0x0470: 70 72 65 20 63 6C 61 73 73 3D 27 43 54 65 78 74   pre class='CText
0x0480: 27 3E 0D 0A 0D 0A 45 72 72 6F 72 20 4D 65 73 73   '>....Error Mess
0x0490: 61 67 65 3A 0D 0A 0D 0A 45 72 72 6F 72 20 63 6F   age:....Error co
0x04A0: 6E 76 65 72 74 69 6E 67 20 64 61 74 61 20 74 79   nverting data ty
0x04B0: 70 65 20 6E 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 20 74 6F 20 62   pe nvarchar to b
0x04C0: 69 67 69 6E 74 2E 0D 0A 0D 0A 45 72 72 6F 72 20   igint.....Error 
0x04D0: 53 74 61 63 6B 20 54 72 61 63 65 3A 0D 0A 0D 0A   Stack Trace:....
0x04E0: 20 20 20 61 74 20 53 79 73 74 65 6D 2E 44 61 74      at System.Dat
0x04F0: 61 2E 53 71 6C 43 6C 69 65 6E 74 2E 53 71 6C 43   a.SqlClient.SqlC
0x0500: 6F 6E 6E 65 63 74 69 6F 6E 2E 4F 6E 45 72 72 6F   onnection.OnErro
0x0510: 72 28 53 71 6C 45 78 63 65 70 74 69 6F 6E 20 65   r(SqlException e
0x0520: 78 63 65 70 74 69 6F 6E 2C 20 42 6F 6F 6C 65 61   xception, Boolea
0x0530: 6E 20 62 72 65 61 6B 43 6F 6E 6E 65 63 74 69 6F   n breakConnectio
0x0540: 6E 29 0D 0A 20 20 20 61 74 20 53 79 73 74 65 6D   n)..   at System
0x0550: 2E 44 61 74 61 2E 53 71 6C 43 6C 69 65 6E 74 2E   .Data.SqlClient.
0x0560: 53 71 6C 49 6E 74 65 72 6E 61 6C 43 6F 6E 6E 65   SqlInternalConne
0x0570: 63 74 69 6F 6E 2E 4F 6E 45 72 72 6F 72 28 53 71   ction.OnError(Sq
0x0580: 6C 45 78 63 65 70 74 69 6F 6E 20 65 78 63 65 70   lException excep
0x0590: 74 69 6F 6E 2C 20 42 6F 6F 6C 65 61 6E 20 62 72   tion, Boolean br
0x05A0: 65 61 6B 43 6F 6E 6E 65 63 74 69 6F 6E 29 0D 0A   eakConnection)..
0x05B0: 20 20 20 61 74 20 53 79 73 74 65 6D 2E 44 61 74      at System.Dat
0x05C0: 61 2E 53 71 6C 43 6C 69 65 6E 74 2E 54 64 73 50   a.SqlClient.TdsP
0x05D0: 61 72 73 65 72 2E 54 68 72 6F 77 45 78 63 65 70   arser.ThrowExcep
0x05E0: 74 69 6F 6E 41 6E 64 57 61 72 6E 69 6E 67 28 54   tionAndWarning(T
0x05F0: 64 73 50 61 72 73 65 72 53 74 61 74 65 4F 62 6A   dsParserStateObj
0x0600: 65 63 74 20 73 74 61 74 65 4F 62 6A 29 0D 0A 20   ect stateObj).. 
0x0610: 20 20 61 74 20 53 79 73 74 65 6D 2E 44 61 74 61     at System.Data
0x0620: 2E 53 71 6C 43 6C 69 65 6E 74 2E 54 64 73 50 61   .SqlClient.TdsPa
0x0630: 72 73 65 72 2E 52 75 6E 28 52 75 6E 42 65 68 61   rser.Run(RunBeha
0x0640: 76 69 6F 72 20 72 75 6E 42 65 68 61 76 69 6F 72   vior runBehavior
0x0650: 2C 20 53 71 6C 43 6F 6D 6D 61 6E 64 20 63 6D 64   , SqlCommand cmd
0x0660: 48 61 6E 64 6C 65 72 2C 20 53 71 6C 44 61 74 61   Handler, SqlData
0x0670: 52 65 61 64 65 72 20 64 61 74 61 53 74 72 65 61   Reader dataStrea
0x0680: 6D 2C 20 42 75 6C 6B 43 6F 70 79 53 69 6D 70 6C   m, BulkCopySimpl
0x0690: 65 52 65 73 75 6C 74 53 65 74 20 62 75 6C 6B 43   eResultSet bulkC
0x06A0: 6F 70 79 48 61 6E 64 6C 65 72 2C 20 54 64 73 50   opyHandler, TdsP
0x06B0: 61 72 73 65 72 53 74 61 74 65 4F 62 6A 65 63 74   arserStateObject
0x06C0: 20 73 74 61 74 65 4F 62 6A 29 0D 0A 20 20 20 61    stateObj)..   a
0x06D0: 74 20 53 79 73 74 65 6D 2E 44 61 74 61 2E 53 71   t System.Data.Sq
0x06E0: 6C 43 6C 69 65 6E 74 2E 53 71 6C 44 61 74 61 52   lClient.SqlDataR
0x06F0: 65 61 64 65 72 2E 48 61 73 4D 6F 72 65 52 6F 77   eader.HasMoreRow
0x0700: 73 28 29 0D 0A 20 20 20 61 74 20 53 79 73 74 65   s()..   at Syste
0x0710: 6D 2E 44 61 74 61 2E 53 71 6C 43 6C 69 65 6E 74   m.Data.SqlClient
0x0720: 2E 53 71 6C 44 61 74 61 52 65 61 64 65 72 2E 52   .SqlDataReader.R
0x0730: 65 61 64 49 6E 74 65 72 6E 61 6C 28 42 6F 6F 6C   eadInternal(Bool
0x0740: 65 61 6E 20 73 65 74 54 69 6D 65 6F 75 74 29 0D   ean setTimeout).
0x0750: 0A 20 20 20 61 74 20 53 79 73 74 65 6D 2E 44 61   .   at System.Da
0x0760: 74 61 2E 53 71 6C 43 6C 69 65 6E 74 2E 53 71 6C   ta.SqlClient.Sql
0x0770: 44 61 74 61 52 65 61 64 65 72 2E 52 65 61 64 28   DataReader.Read(
0x0780: 29 0D 0A 20 20 20 61 74 20 61 78 61 63 6F 72 65   )..   at axacore
0x0790: 2E 6C 69 62 2E 64 62 2E 44 62 53 65 73 73 69 6F   .lib.db.DbSessio
0x07A0: 6E 33 2E 52 65 61 64 28 29 0D 0A 0D 0A 3C 2F 70   n3.Read()....</p
0x07B0: 72 65 3E 0D 0A 0D 0A 3C 2F 73 70 61 6E 3E 0D 0A   re>....</span>..
0x07C0: 0D 0A
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out. This is what I needed to know. Now I can diagnose this at the server level rather than mess with base 64 encode/decode functions.

Comment: did you use a tool to get this output?

Comment: @jini: yes - but it is one I wrote.  It isn't a particularly beautiful interface; indeed, I tried to fix it up a bit last month but didn't complete the exercise, but I don't use it all that often.  Contact me (see my profile) if you want the code 'as is'.  Actually, the biggest problem I had was getting the 2624 bytes of pasted base-64 string into a file; I couldn't use 'cat > file' and had to do it in 'vim' instead.  The sub-headings in the answer were simply the result of slapping 3 hashes ('`#`') in front of a line in the output.